# the MutationObserver only get the last 'after-click' changed nodes notify

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

first, we navigate to page http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/index.php .
[the init page pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lxm6g.png)
when the page loaded, we inject a piece of javascript code

```
// html5 MutationObserver to monitor new nodes generated
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations ){
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
      if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
          // when new element generated
          console.log("child list: ");
          console.log(mutation);
      } else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
          // when attr change
          console.log("attributes: ");
          console.log(mutation);
      }
  });
});

observer.observe(window.document, {
  subtree: true,
  childList: true,
  attributes: true,
  attributeFilter: ['src', 'href', 'action']
});


function treeWalkerFilter(element) {
  if (element.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
  }
}
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
      document,
      NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
      treeWalkerFilter,
      false
  );

// traverse element nodes
while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
  console.log("[*] processing node " + treeWalker.currentNode.tagName + ' ' + treeWalker.currentNode.id);
  if(treeWalker.currentNode.click && treeWalker.currentNode.tagName == 'A')
    {
        treeWalker.currentNode.click();
        //break;
    }
}
```

like the code above, we use treeWalker to traverse dom tree, and click the nodes, I expect that the MututionObserver will get 4 new mutation nodes to notify, but the log shows that it was only one(the last one that when we click the 'send xml' tag in page) [the console log pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvJOI.png)

```
console log:[*] processing node HTML
console log:[*] processing node HEAD
console log:[*] processing node META
console log:[*] processing node TITLE
console log:[*] processing node LINK
console log:[*] processing node SCRIPT
console log:[*] processing node BODY
console log:[*] processing node TABLE
console log:[*] processing node TBODY
console log:[*] processing node TR
console log:[*] processing node TD
console log:[*] processing node A
console log:ajax open, url: artists.php
console log:ajax send,data:
loading: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/artists.php
console log:[*] processing node A
console log:ajax open, url: categories.php
console log:ajax send,data:
loading: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/categories.php
console log:[*] processing node A
console log:ajax open, url: titles.php
console log:ajax send,data:
loading: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/titles.php
console log:[*] processing node A
console log:ajax open, url: showxml.php
console log:ajax setheader, header: content-type
console log:ajax send,data: <xml><node name="nodename1">nodetext1</node><node name="nodename2">nodetext2</node></xml>
loading: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/showxml.php
console log:[*] processing node A
console log:[*] processing node TR
console log:[*] processing node TD
console log:[*] processing node DIV contentDiv
console log:[*] processing node TR
console log:[*] processing node TD
console log:[*] processing node DIV infoDiv
console log:[*] processing node TR
console log:[*] processing node TD
console log:[*] processing node DIV xmlDiv
console log:child list:
console log:[object MutationRecord]
```

if we click the first tag('artists') and break the loop(uncomment the 'break' in while loop), we can get the first mutation nodes notify, like below [the console log pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twRES.png):

```
console log:[*] processing node HTML
console log:[*] processing node HEAD
console log:[*] processing node META
console log:[*] processing node TITLE
console log:[*] processing node LINK
console log:[*] processing node SCRIPT
console log:[*] processing node BODY
console log:[*] processing node TABLE
console log:[*] processing node TBODY
console log:[*] processing node TR
console log:[*] processing node TD
console log:[*] processing node A
console log:ajax open, url: artists.php
console log:ajax send,data:
loading: http://testphp.vulnweb.com/AJAX/artists.php
console log:child list:
console log:[object MutationRecord]
console log:child list:
console log:[object MutationRecord]
```

so my questions are how to get all the mutation nodes to notify when my code click all the button/A link that may make the dom tree change, any suggestions will help, thanks.

Comment: Try clicking asynchronously: `setTimeout(el => el.click(), 0, treeWalker.currentNode)`

Comment: i try it, but the result are the same as `treeWalker.currentNode.click()`